# C++ error: ISO C++ forbids declaration. with no type

Tags: c++

Can someone help me with this problem please?
How can i do make this lines to can compile good?

> ClientManager.h:332: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
>
> ClientManager.h:332: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'TPacketGDCombatZoneResetRanking' with no type
>
> ClientManager.h:333: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
>
> ClientManager.h:333: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'TPacketGDCombatZoneSkillsCache' with no type

**ClientManager.h** line 332 - 333

```
void        CombatZoneResetRanking(const TPacketGDCombatZoneResetRanking* p);
void        UpdateSkillsCache(const TPacketGDCombatZoneSkillsCache* p);
```

**ClientManager.cpp** function

```
void CClientManager::CombatZoneResetRanking(const TPacketGDCombatZoneResetRanking* p)
{
    CDBManager::instance().DirectQuery("UPDATE player.player SET combat_zone_rank = 0 WHERE combat_zone_rank > 0");
    std::auto_ptr<SQLMsg> pMsg(CDBManager::instance().DirectQuery("SELECT * FROM player.combat_zone_ranking_weekly ORDER BY memberPoints DESC LIMIT 3"));   
    if (pMsg->Get()->uiNumRows == 3)
    {
        MYSQL_ROW row;
        int memberRank = 1;
        char szQuery[512 + 1];
        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(pMsg->Get()->pSQLResult)))
        {
            sprintf(szQuery, "UPDATE player.player SET combat_zone_rank = '%d' WHERE name = '%s'", memberRank, row[0]);
            CDBManager::instance().DirectQuery(szQuery);
            memberRank++;
        }
    }
    else {
        sys_err("The giving ranking medals not was possible because not was exist 3 players on ranking weekly.");
    }
    CDBManager::instance().DirectQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE player.combat_zone_ranking_weekly");
}
void CClientManager::UpdateSkillsCache(const TPacketGDCombatZoneSkillsCache* p)
{
    char szQuery[2048 + 1];
    sprintf(szQuery, 
        "INSERT INTO player.combat_zone_skills_cache (pid, skillLevel1, skillLevel2, skillLevel3, skillLevel4, skillLevel5, skillLevel6) "
            "VALUES('%d', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d') "
                "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE skillLevel1 = '%d', skillLevel2 = '%d', skillLevel3 = '%d', skillLevel4 = '%d', skillLevel5 = '%d', skillLevel6 = '%d'", 
                    p->dwPID, p->dwSkillLevel1, p->dwSkillLevel2, p->dwSkillLevel3, p->dwSkillLevel4, p->dwSkillLevel5, p->dwSkillLevel6, p->dwSkillLevel1, p->dwSkillLevel2, p->dwSkillLevel3, p->dwSkillLevel4, p->dwSkillLevel5, p->dwSkillLevel6);
    CDBManager::instance().DirectQuery(szQuery);
}
```

cases:

```
case HEADER_GD_COMBAT_ZONE_RESET_RANKING:
    CombatZoneResetRanking((TPacketGDCombatZoneResetRanking*)data);
    break;
    
case HEADER_GD_COMBAT_ZONE_SKILLS_CACHE:
    UpdateSkillsCache((TPacketGDCombatZoneSkillsCache*)data);
    break;
```

Comment: Where are the types `TPacketGDCombatZoneResetRanking` and `TPacketGDCombatZoneSkillsCache` defined?

Comment: You forgot to `#include` the header that declares `TPacketGDCombatZoneResetRanking` and `TPacketGDCombatZoneSkillsCache`.

Answer (score 0):

`n.m.`'s comment hits it on the head.

The compiler error message here is very unfortunate (and suggests that you're using an outdated version of GCC). The problem is that the compiler cannot find the types you're using there, so instead of reading the parameter as `const some_type* name_of_parameter`, it reads it as `const name_of_parameter other_stuff_that_shouldnt_be_here`, and complains that 1) you can't name the parameter without first giving a type and 2) you have some unexpected tokens (namely, the `*`) after the parameter name.

But the real problem is that the types aren't declared, leading the compiler down the wrong path.

You need to either declare the types with forward declarations, or include the headers that define them.

Comment: when i try to define , i get error , cannot find "defined object"

Comment: You'll have to go into more detail on that. Like show the code you use to define, and the exact error message.